# OpenMP and Nested for loops with continue statements

Tags: c, openmp

I have the following the code:

```
int myArray[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
double EV = 0;
for(short a1 = 1; a1 <= 6; ++a1)
{
    ++myArray[a1-1];
    if(....)
    {
        --myArray[a1-1];
        continue;
    }
    EV = myEVFunc();
    if(EV...)
    {

        for(short a2 = 1; a2 <=6 ; ++a2)
        {
            ++myArray[a2-1];
            if(....)
            {
                --myArray[a2-1];
                continue;
            }
            EV = myEVFunc();
            if(EV...)
            {
                for(short a3 = 1; a3 <= 6; ++a3)
                {
                    ++myArray[a3-1];
                    if(....)
                    {
                        --myArray[a3-1];
                        continue;
                    }
                    EV = myEVFunc();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use OpenMP to parallelize the loops. the code compiles fine when i place 
 `#pragma omp parallel for` in front of the outermost for loop. However it gives incorrect results. I suspect two issues the continue statements inside the loops and the fact that there are shared variables in the nested loops. 
Is it possible to use OpenMP with this code snippet, if so can anyone please give me the correct syntax. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll point out a couple obvious things:

1.) `double EV = 0;` is declared outside the outer loop. Therefore it will be shared by all the threads. So you'll have a ***race condition*** at `EV = myEVFunc();` and at each access to `EV`.

The solution to this is to declare it inside the loop. That will make it private to each thread.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(short a1 = 1; a1 <= 6; ++a1)
    {
        ++myArray[a1-1];
        if(....)
        {
            --myArray[a1-1];
            continue;
        }
        double EV = myEVFunc();
        if(EV...)
        ...
```

2.) Another (sorta) issue is that your outer-loop only has 6 iterations. So you won't get more than 6 threads. Furthermore, you could get load-balancing issues with say 4 cores...

Comment: You could use "#pragma omp atomic" for the ++ and -- statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use thread private if that is more of what you need

It will give a private copy of the variable EV to each thread. Initially it will be uninitialized in these threads unless you use copyin as well.

With out copyin the directive would look like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(EV)
```

This avoids the race condition and allows EV to act independntly in each thread

Answer (score 0):

you also have a race condition with the array access e.g. `++myArray[a1-1];`
and `++myArray[a2-1];` from different threads.
additionally you need to declare all loop counter private, `a1` (is default private because of pragma omp for, but not), `a2, a3`..

Maybe you can find another way of writing your loops because all these conditional statements within the loop is usually not very efficient.